# sympy fails to find the volume of a sphere with a two fold integral

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

The following script computes the volume of a sphere

```
from sympy import sqrt, symbols, integrate
x,y = symbols('x y ')
R = symbols('R', constant=True) # radius
f=sqrt(R**2 - x**2 - y**2) # explicit equation for an octant
myInt= integrate(f, (y, 0, sqrt(R**2 - x**2)), (x, 0, R))
8*myInt
```

I can compute this by hand using the substitution y=sqrt(R^2 - x^2) sin (theta).

The result should be 4 pi R^3/3.  SymPy spins and gives garbage.

Answer (score 0):

`sqrt(R ** 2 - x ** 2 - y ** 2)` cannot be easily integrated and cannot be easily reduced to something integrateble. But if you transform this expression from cartesian coordinate system to cylindrical coordinate system it becomes `sqrt(R ** 2 - r ** 2)`, so you can compute this double integral.

```py
from sympy import symbols, integrate, sin, cos, pi, sqrt, simplify

x, y, r, theta, phi = symbols('x, y, r, theta, phi', real=True, positive=True)
R = symbols('R', real=True, constant=True, positive=True)

octant_cartesian = sqrt(R ** 2 - x ** 2 - y ** 2)
octant_cylindrical = octant_cartesian.subs(x, r * cos(theta)).subs(y, r * sin(theta))

# f(x, y) * dx * dy -> f(r, theta) * r * dtheta * dr
area = 8 * integrate(simplify(octant_cylindrical * r), (r, 0, R), (theta, 0, pi / 2))
print(area)
```

Alternatively you can compute sphere volume as a triple integral of one in spherical coordinates.

```py
# f(x,y,z) * dx * dy * dz -> f(r, phi, theta) * r ** 2 * sin(phi) * dr * dphi * dtheta
area = 8 * integrate(r ** 2 * sin(phi), (r, 0, R), (phi, 0, pi / 2), (theta, 0, pi / 2))
print(area)
```

Comment: That is right,  I actually did that. I thought that ``SymPy`` internally would do something like that for me.  Thanks

Comment: I think main reason why he couldn't do it is because he have no way of knowing how x and y are related to each other (the values on ortogonal axes), so he could not possibly come up with this substitution.